# Using Cypress, how to test for an element not existing?

Tags: testing, cypress

Testing for an element existing is as easy as

```
cy.get('.hello');
```

How does one assert that this element does not exist?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily just go

```
cy
  .get('.hello')
  .should('not.exist');
```

Works just ok for me. However, you need to be careful about timing for such a command. For example, if you have this command right after your page loads, it can give you a false positive, because the element hasn’t been loaded and therefore does not exist in DOM.

For me, the best practice would be to do additional `cy.get` on something I am pretty sure is loaded or `.should('be.visible')` at the time the other element does not exist.

For example, if you have a modal that receives an input and then disappears after input is submitted, I would assert on visibility of page that is below the modal, like this:

```
cy
  .get('.page-body');

cy
  .get('.modal-trigger')
  .click();

cy
  .get('.modal')
  .should('be.visible')
  .type('text')
  .get('.submit')
  .click();

cy
  .get('.page-body')
  .should('be.visible');

cy
  .get('.modal')
  .should('not.exist');
```

Since Cypress checks if an element is not covered by any other element, `cy.get('.page-body')` should give you a pretty good reference on the current situation in your app. Additional check for `cy.get('.modal').should('not.exist')` is just another way to make sure that everything happened as intended. Sometimes this makes sense, sometimes it’s overkill.